# What VBA coding in a Userform can I use to find a cell based upon row & column content, and then update that cell?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, userform

I am a complete beginner to VBA, truely.

I am trying to create a user form that will update the number of tasks a person completes on a given date as listed on a spreadsheet. I envision the Userform having two bottons (which are hidden and appear as the conditions of the subroutine). I am working on a Mac, by the way, and I know that will have VBA coding implications for use on a PC och vice versa.

The example sheet is this:

[image: Sample, simple spreadsheet table I want to search and update with Userforms and VBA]

The example Userform (a) is this:

[image: First stage of user form where I would like for the userform to serch the sheet for the person and date and retrieve the number of tasks in the appropriate cell]

For argument's sake, let say I want to update or input the number of tasks that Greg completed on the 7th of May (2013/05/07).

I would like for the Userform to proceed something like this:

Entering person and date:

[image]

Then, retrieving number of tasks for Greg on the 7th after button click:

[image]

Now, I want to input that I know Greg completed 6 tasks on the 7th and I click the second button (now visible and the first button hidden):

[image]

And the result in the spreadsheet:

[image]

I ought to input some code here, but my skills and the completeness of the code are wanting. But I will put in what I have:

```
Option Explicit

'Subroutine when clicking the first ("find") button
Private Sub btnfind_Click()
    lbltasks.Vissible = True
    txttasks.Visible = True
    btnupdate.Visible = True
    btnfind.Visible = False

'Defining variables
    Dim pr01 As String
    Dim dt01 As Date
    Dim tsk01 As Integer

'Assigning variables to inputs
    pr01 = txtperson.Text
    dt01 = txtdate.Text
    tsk01 = txttask.Text

'Looking for Name in column "A"
    ' ? ? ?

'Looking for inut Date in row "1"
    ' ? ? ?

'Retrieving the existing number of tasks according to name and date
'and showing number in the 'tasks' text input box in the user form
     ' ? ? ?
End Sub

'Subroutine when clicking the Second ("update") button
Private Sub btnupdate_Click()

'Paste updated Number of tasks in appropriate cells according to name and date
'The new number of tasks should over write what was there previously
    ' ? ? ?

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Please study it and use the macro record function in Excel to grasp a lot more:

```
Option Explicit
Public frmName As Variant 'store row of name
Public frmDate As Variant 'store column of date

'Subroutine when clicking the first ("find") button
Private Sub btnfind_Click()
'Defining variables
    Dim pr01 As String
    Dim dt01 As Date
    Dim tsk01 As Integer

'Assigning variables to inputs
    pr01 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
    dt01 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
    tsk01 = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text

'Looking for Name in column "A"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        frmName = .Columns("A").Find(pr01).Row
    End With


'Looking for inut Date in row "1"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        frmDate = .Rows(1).Find(CDate(dt01)).Column
    End With

    If frmName Is Nothing Or frmDate Is Nothing Then
        'not found
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Retrieving the existing number of tasks according to name and date
'and showing number in the 'tasks' text input box in the user form
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = .Cells(frmName, frmDate)
    End With

End Sub

'Subroutine when clicking the Second ("update") button
Private Sub btnupdate_Click()

'Paste updated Number of tasks in appropriate cells according to name and date
'The new number of tasks should over write what was there previously
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        .Cells(frmName, frmDate) = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @glh .  I am still running into problems though.  When I run the VBA/Macro, I get en error: "run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set." when I click 'debug' I come to line: `'Looking for inut Date in row "1"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        frmDate = .Rows(1).Find(CDate(dt01)).Column
    End With`

Comment: I tested this ok... That's 3 lines though. Also be sure you set the variables correctly. Interestingly it ran ok past the previous line.